# How to check scroll of page in clear js

Tags: javascript, css

I've got footer which is on the bottom of page (when the page is `scrollable`). My script is checking `scrollable` 2 times per second.

If I want to scroll the page down to see the footer I can't do this.

```
let check_height=setInterval(function()
{
    var height_of_logo=document.querySelector('header').offsetHeight-2;
    document.querySelector('footer').style.position='absolute';
    var height_of_main=documentquerySelector('footer').offsetTop-document.querySelector('header').offsetHeight;
    var height_of_body=document.querySelector('form, table').offsetHeight+height_of_logo+2+document.querySelector('footer').offsetHeight;
    var height_of_body_real=document.body.querySelector('footer').offsetHeight+document.querySelector('footer').offsetTop;
    if(height_of_body_real<=height_of_body)
    {
        document.querySelector('main').style.height=document.querySelector('form, table').offsetHeight+'px';
        document.querySelector('footer').style.position='static';
    }
    else
    {
        document.querySelector('main').style.height=height_of_main+'px';
    }
}, 500);
```

`document.body.querySelector('footer').style.position = 'absolute';` is changing scroll, so I need than scroll to scroll which was before checking.

How can I check scroll of page?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Check this `document.children` in console.

There you have scrollTop and more.

Answer (score 0):

By getting `scrollTop` property, you can get scroll height of every scrollable DOM element.

```
let element = document.getElementById('foo')
console.log(element.scrollTop)
```

Comment: I don't know why but it didn't worked that why I asked.